# Solving the boundary value problem by means of Galerkin method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a task which should be solved with Galerkin method:
$$
y''-0.5x^2y+2y=x^2 \\
  y(1.6)+0.7y'(1.6)=2 (1)\\
  y(1.9)=0.8 (2)
$$
I already solved it with other methods so the correct answer I know, but I can't solve it   exactly with Galerkin method.

The task was programmed in Mathematica. For the simple boundary values such as:
$$
y(a)=L\\
  y(b)=Q
$$
where L and Q - digits, a and b - boundaries of range.

$\phi_k$ for the simple boundary values has appearance:
$\phi_k(x)=(x-a)(x-b)^k$

so the answer we can get like:
$y(x)=\phi_0(x)+\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\phi_k(x)$

The main problem is finding $\phi_k$ for boundary values such as (1) and (2). Maybe someone already faced the same problem.

Comment: What is the meaning of $2(1)$ and $0.8(2)$ ? Are they typo?

Comment: @doraemonpaul, It just the references are used in the last sentence (I meant digits (1) and (2)).